# How to I count the number of documents which have same value and group them using another field in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Suppose I have few documents like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce1f9cb4a5d097c9061c8"),
    "job_id" : 1,
    "score" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce200cb4a5d097c9061cb"),
    "job_id" : 1,
    "score" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce206cb4a5d097c9061ce"),
    "job_id" : 1,
    "score" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce210cb4a5d097c9061d3"),
    "job_id" : 1,
    "score" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce21acb4a5d097c9061d6"),
    "job_id" : 2,
    "score" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce224cb4a5d097c9061df"),
    "job_id" : 2,
    "score" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce230cb4a5d097c9061e2"),
    "job_id" : 2,
    "score" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecce239cb4a5d097c9061e5"),
    "job_id" : 2,
    "score" : 0
}
```

How do I group them according to their job_id and get an aggregated result having occurence of scores?
Like this:

```
{
    "job_id": 1,
    "result": {
        0:1,
        1:1,
        2:2
    }
},
{
    "job_id": 2,
    "result": {
        0:3,
        2:1
    }
}
```

Since in job_id 2, O occurred 3 times  and 2 occurred 1 time, hence this result.

I tried many different methods and tried to do grouping but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Mongo version 4.0+ you can use this following aggregation that utilizes [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to manipulate the data structure. the reason we need Mongo version 4.0 is the usage of [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) in the pipeline due to the restriction of object keys must be type'd string in order for the `$arrayToObject` to work.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {job: "$job_id", score: "$score"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.job",
            scoreResults: {$push: {v: "$count", k: {$toString: "$_id.score"}}}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            job_id: "$_id",
            result: {$arrayToObject: "$scoreResults"} 
        }
    }
])
```

On older Mongo versions you'll either have to do the final structure conversion that would have been done by the `$arrayToObject` in code or change the required output format to be a feasible structure to obtain by the available commands for that Mongo version.